# Can I stop a User from returning to the previous page in React Navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am a little new to this. I need to stop a user from navigating back to the previous page after submitting details. I need your help. Is there a way I can prevent a user from returning back to a specific Screen in a stack. Here is a snippet of my Stack.

After ADD_CUSTOMER_DETAILS_2 once the user navigates to ADD_CUSTOMER_PHOTOS, I would like to prevent the user from navigating back to ADD_CUSTOMER_DETAILS_2

```
 function AddCustomerStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      headerMode="screen"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: true,
        headerBackTitleVisible: false,
        headerLeft: () => <ActionBarImage />
      }}
      initialRouteName={Screens.CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_HOME}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Screens.CAMERA}
        options={{ title: '', headerShown: false }}
        component={CameraScreen}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Screens.FACE_DETECTION_CAMERA}
        options={{ title: '', headerShown: false }}
        component={FaceDetectionCamera}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Screens.SHOW_IMAGE}
        options={{ title: '' }}
        component={ShowImage}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Screens.TYPE_OF_CUSTOMER}
        options={{ title: 'CUSTOMER SIGN UP' }}
        component={TypeOfCustomer}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Screens.ADD_SERIAL_NUMBER}
        options={{ title: 'CUSTOMER SIGN UP' }}
        component={AddSerialNumber}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Screens.ADD_CUSTOMER_DETAILS_1}
        options={{ title: 'CUSTOMER SIGN UP' }}
        component={AddCustomerDetails1}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Screens.ADD_CUSTOMER_DETAILS_2}
        options={{ title: 'CUSTOMER SIGN UP' }}
        component={AddCustomerDetails2}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Screens.ADD_CUSTOMER_PHOTOS}
        options={{ title: 'CUSTOMER SIGN UP' }}
        component={AddCustomerPhotos}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Screens.REGISTRATION_SAVED}
        options={{ title: 'SAVED REGISTRATIONS' }}
        component={RegistrationSavedSucces}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Screens.ADD_CUSTOMER_DETAILS_PREVIEW}
        options={{ title: 'PREVIEW' }}
        component={AddCustomerDetailsPreview}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Screens.SIGNATURE}
        options={{ title: 'SIGNATURE' }}
        component={Signature}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Screens.SAVED_REGISTRATIONS}
        options={{ title: 'SAVED REGISTRATIONS' }}
        component={SavedRegistrations}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Screens.CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_HOME}
        options={{ title: 'CUSTOMER' }}
        component={CustomerRegistrationHome}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{ title: '' }}
        name={Screens.CUSTOMER_SEARCH_BY_OTP}
        component={CustomerSearchbyOTP}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{ title: '' }}
        name={Screens.EDIT_CUSTOMER_DETAILS}
        component={EditCustomerDeatils}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Screens.CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_SUCCESSFUL}
        options={{ title: '' }}
        component={CustomerRegistrationSuccessful}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Screens.CUSTOMER_SEARCH}
        options={{ title: 'Search Customer' }}
        component={CustomerSearch}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Screens.ADD_CORPORATE_DETAILS_1}
        options={{ title: 'CUSTOMER SIGN UP' }}
        component={AddCorporateDetails1}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Screens.ADD_MINOR_DETAILS_1}
        options={{ title: 'CUSTOMER SIGN UP' }}
        component={AddMinorDetails1}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Screens.SIM_SWAP}
        options={{ title: 'ADD NEW SIM' }}
        component={SimSwap}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Screens.SIM_ADD}
        options={{ title: '' }}
        component={AddNewSIM}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Screens.ADD_NEW_SIM_DETAILS}
        options={{ title: '' }}
        component={AddNewSIMDetails}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Comment: I suppose you have a back button on that `ADD_CUSTOMER_PHOTOS` screen, right? Or are you testing on an android device and you want to prevent the hardware native back?

Comment: No I have no back button on that Screen. 
I used the BackHandler on android and it Worked. However Once I navigate to that Screen it disables the back button in the entire application. Any other Ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the component set a state when a user has submitted the details,

```
useEffect(() => {
if(someState) {
  history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
  window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    history.go(1);
  };
}
},[someState])
```